# Terraform resources created with `for_each` - use in other Terraform scripts

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have terraform script that creates N security groups:

```
variable "security_groups" {
    default     = {
        "sg1" = "Security group 1"
        "sg2" = "Security group 2"
    }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "example" {
    for_each = var.security_groups

    name                   = each.key
    description            = each.value

    vpc_id                 = aws_vpc.example.id
    revoke_rules_on_delete = false

    egress {
        from_port   = 0
        to_port     = 0
        protocol    = "-1"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
}
```

..and I have another Terraform script that creates IAM policy,

this one has to reference N Security groups created by first script in Resource section:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "operator_policy" {
  name        = "${var.iam_prefix}-operator"
  path        = "/"
  description = "Policy for operator"
  policy      = <<-EOF
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Action": [
                    "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
                    "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                    "ec2:UpdateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsEgress",
                    "ec2:UpdateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsIngress",
                    "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
                    "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress"
                ],
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Resource": [
                    "sg1 ARN",
                    "sgN ARN"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    EOF
}
```

Is it feasible somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combo of [jsonencode](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsonencode.html) with [values](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/values.html) and [spat expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions/splat.html):

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "operator_policy" {
  name        = "${var.iam_prefix}-operator"
  path        = "/"
  description = "Policy for operator"
  policy      = <<-EOF
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Action": [
                    "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
                    "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                    "ec2:UpdateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsEgress",
                    "ec2:UpdateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsIngress",
                    "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
                    "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress"
                ],
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Resource": ${jsonencode(values(aws_security_group.example)[*].arn)}
            }
        ]
    }
    EOF
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using string templates to generate JSON, it's more robust to generate the entire value using [the `jsonencode` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsonencode.html), because then Terraform can evaluate the argument as a normal expression and be sure to generate a valid JSON representation of the result:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "operator_policy" {
  name        = "${var.iam_prefix}-operator"
  path        = "/"
  description = "Policy for operator"
  policy      = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = [
          "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
          "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
          "ec2:UpdateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsEgress",
          "ec2:UpdateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsIngress",
          "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
          "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
        ]
        Effect = "Allow"
        Resource = [
          "sg1 ARN",
          "sgN ARN",
        ]
      },
    ]
  })
}
```

As well as guaranteeing that the result will always be valid JSON syntax, using Terraform's expression language to build your policy value also means you can use all of [Terraform's expression operators](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions/), including [`for` expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions/for.html) to read the `arn` attribute from each of your security groups:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "operator_policy" {
  name        = "${var.iam_prefix}-operator"
  path        = "/"
  description = "Policy for operator"
  policy      = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = [
          "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
          "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
          "ec2:UpdateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsEgress",
          "ec2:UpdateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsIngress",
          "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
          "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
        ]
        Effect = "Allow"
        Resource = [
          for sg in aws_security_group.example : sg.arn
        ],
      },
    ]
  })
}
```